# Issue with a NVM install of node where Cron job isn't able to see sailsjs models

Tags: cron, sails.js, nvm

I've a job that fetches data from a web API every 5 minutes on an Ubuntu server:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/<u>/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.5/bin/node /home/<u>/api/jobs/fetch-data.js >> /home/<u>/log/fetch.log 2>&1
```

If I run:

```
/home/<u>/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.5/bin/node /home/<u>/api/jobs/fetch-data.js
```

from my command line, everything works fine. But when the cron job tries to run it errors out on that it cannot find the model that I'm using within the task.

I've installed node using node version manager.  I've a much simplier task that is able to execute with local node_module depenencies just fine, it seems as though whatever bootstrapping that takes place with the:

```
sails.load()
```

Method isn't playing nice.  I'm pretty new to the node world so the inner workings of things are still very much "and magic happens" behind the sheets.  I'm hoping someone else has already ran into this in the past and it's just a simple mistake I'm making.

I've written a small little test of what my larger api fecting process does that just tries to pull some events from the database and write them to the console:

```html
var Sails   = require('sails');

Sails.load(function(err, sails) {
   if(err) {
       throw err;
   }

    Events.find({}).exec(function(err, events) {
        if(err) throw new Error(err);
        
        events.forEach(function(event) {
            console.log(event);
            process.exit();
        });
        
    });
});
```

This code running with `nvm use 0.12`, then `node api/jobs/simple.js` or just using:

```
/home/<u>/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.5/bin/node /home/<u>/api/jobs/simple.js
```

works just fine.

But this:

```
 /home/<u>/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.5/bin/node /home/<u>/api/jobs/simple.js
```

in the cron job settings presents the error that Events not defined

[EDIT]
I don't consider this an answer but I used: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-schedule

changed 4 lines of code and at least I'm able to schedule the data fetch now.

I hope I can get some help on the cron-nvm-sails issue still though.